# Django: Query set to get AVG doesn't work

Tags: python, django

Currently, I try to get the average of all the answers to a specific question in my
database. To achieve that I wrote the following query set. The answers are all numeric,
but there still seems to be a problem with my query set. I receive the following error message
`function avg(text) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT AVG("surveys_answer"."answer") AS "avg" FROM "surveys...`

```
answers = Question.objects.filter(
    focus=QuestionFocus.AGE,
    survey__event=self.request.event,
    survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
).aggregate(avg=Avg('answers__answer'))
```

**models.py**

```
class Question(TimeStampedModel):
    survey = models.ForeignKey([...])
    question_set = models.ForeignKey([...])
    title = models.CharField([...])
    help_text = models.TextField([...])
    type = models.CharField([...])
    focus = models.CharField([...])
    required = models.BooleanField([...])
    position = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField([...])

class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    response = models.ForeignKey([...])
    answer = models.TextField([...])
    choices = models.ManyToManyField([...])
```

Comment: `answer` is a `TextField`. So how would you calculate the "average" on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The answers are all numeric, but there still seems to be a problem with my query set.

That's not a problem with your queryset. That is a problem with your model and database. If your values are numerical, you need to use an `IntegerField`, `DecimalField`, `FloatField`, or something else that stores data numerically in the database. For example:

```
class Answer(TimeStampedModel):
    question = models.ForeignKey(related_name='answers')
    response = models.ForeignKey([...])
    answer = models.IntegerField([...])
    choices = models.ManyToManyField([...])
```

Strictly speaking, you can convert it to numerical data in the database, but that is very unsafe, and will only let the modeling problem persist:

```
from django.db.models import IntegerField
from django.db.models.functions import Cast

answers = Question.objects.filter(
    focus=QuestionFocus.AGE,
    survey__event=self.request.event,
    survey__template=settings.SURVEY_POST_EVENT,
).aggregate(avg=Avg(Cast('answers__answer', output_field=IntegerField())))
```

But it is a lot better to prevent ever entering non-numerical data in the database, than trying to mitigate the problem through queries.

Comment: Thank you Willem, that seems to work. I understand your point. However, I use the answer field also for Strings & Emails "if" the QuestionFocus is different. E.g. `focus=QuestionFocus.FEEDBACK` would be open text from the same field. Considering that, would you say your second suggestion that works is okay?

Comment: @JoeyCoder: it will likely work. Although itm might not be ideal modeling, since then you need to enforce these types yourself. You might consider subclassing the answer with different sorts of answers.